# Error 1305 when importing sql dump into mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am importing a sql dump file into MySQL workbench and keep getting the error below. Does this mean the rest of the file/records did not import or only the xxx.getRates portion did not?
Will I be missing records from it? 
Does anyone know what might be causing this?

> 01:29:31 Restoring D:\Projects\CustomerName\Customer Files\xxx-2016-Oct-03.sql
>   Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\tmpru2fjn.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=xxx  < "D:\Projects\CustomerName\Customer Files\xxx-2016-Oct-03.sql
>
> ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 33522: FUNCTION xxx.getRates does not exist
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1
>   01:34:29 Import of D:\Projects\CustomerName\Customer Files\xxx-2016-Oct-03.sql has finished with 1 errors

Comment: We need mor info to help you. In your dump file, search for the `CREATE FUNCTION xxx.getRates` statement. If you find it, add the function declaration in your answer. If you don't find it, then just search for all references of `xxx.getRates` and see if there's a declaration for it (it might be faulty declared as a `CREATE PROCEDURE`  or just not declared at all, which would be your error

Answer (score 11):

When using `mysqldump`, you must explicitly ask for Stored routines to be dumped.  The option is `--routines` if you are running it manually.  If you are running it through some app (Workbench), then look for its mechanism:

```
[ ] Dump Stored Procedures and Functions
[ ] Dump Events
[ ] Dump Triggers
```